# Using regular expressions: making sure a field contains a special character and numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that checks a field and make sure it includes (special characters or numbers) including all the other character as well. I am failing to do it correctly.

I've been using some regular expression sites like http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ to give me some help and make sure I'm getting the right thing, but I'm not.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+=<>?]*$)^([a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+=<>?0-9]{6,15})$
```

It checks for everything although it is required that there is a number in it. But I need it to be required to have a number OR special character.

Comment: Example data would be helpful, what kind of data is in the fields you are checking? What 'special characters' are you looking for?

What have you tried?

Comment: Looks like he's trying to do a password change validator.  You should validate it server side as well, though arguably if someone is going far enough to bypass your password restrictions as to modify the page to accept invalid passwords, they know the drawbacks of using a crappy one and you might as well let them.

Comment: Yes it is more like a password validation. A password (For example) fjhw#fk and dskj3fn should both match fully. I am checking it server side as well, but that's a little easier. I didn't have to do it all in one string.

Comment: Length restrictions are better than content restrictions, and they make passwords easier to remember.  Make sure you also force them to include ancient norse runes and at least one unprintable unicode character and something with a diaeresis.  See the oft cited http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Every time a password validator at some site makes me include a number and punctuations and a capital letter, I mail them the XKCD link Wug mentions. Password validators are evil.

Comment: @Twister1002: Your password suggestions page should be nothing but that comic.  No text.  If they still try to enter a crappy password, you should warn them once, but let them do it.  You should also flag their account as having a crappy password and display the comic everywhere in their profile.

Comment: #Almo and Wug, I would love to! But the higher up says we need to have it like that. I loved that comic btw! Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a number AND a special character:

```
[^\s\w].*\d|\d.*[^\s\w]
```

This requires a number OR a special character:

```
\d|[^\s\w]
```

The pipe character '|' means OR.

This one matches an entire line if there is both a special character AND a number:

```
.*(:?[^\s\w].*\d|\d.*[^\s\w]).*
```

This one matches an entire line if there is a special character OR a number:

```
.*(?:\d|[^\s\w]).*
```

Comment: I think I just found one with your help. Tips to the pipe! This should work as well I think     .+\w|\W

Answer (score 0):

Special characters or numbers? Well, `[^A-Za-z_ ]` is probably good enough then.

Edit:

So, if you are trying to do password validation, then this is really simple with positive lookaheads. Shameless stolen from: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/

```
(           # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])       #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])       #   must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])      #   must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
              .     #     match anything with previous condition checking
                {6,20}  #        length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20 
)
```

Comment: Sorry left out some information on this. I'm needing it to check for letters and make sure it includes a number or special character.